# Can we convert classic pages (Wiki pages and Publishing pages) into modern pages during migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, pnp, sharepointmigrationtool

We want to migrate SharePoint 2010 sites into SharePoint Online and we are going to use ShareGate Migration tool. But we are not sure if the tool  (or other migration tools) do support automatically converting Classic Pages into Modern Pages? or we need to do this manually or using the https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's very likely that you will need to use the [PnP modernization tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-site-pages) to convert these pages.

I recommend you talk to ShareGate support team regarding any support for the converting of classic pages.

Comment: but do you know if there is any migration tool that do this automatically ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, though you might be better off doing your own research. This forum is for SharePoint questions mostly and PnP modernization tools are what Microsoft recommend.